# How to prevent exit blocking script from disabling submit button after it's used

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a script used to prevent navigation away from the page so changes are not lost accidentally. Unfortunately, this also "breaks" the page if the script is activated via submitting the form. So, I can no longer submit the form after I press the submit button an decide to stay on the page.

This **does not** disable the submit button when navigation is done by something *other* than the submit button.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening and allow me to "accidentally" activate this script multiple times while still being able to use my submit button after the popup?

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var unfinished = 'false';
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      if (inputs[i].value != '') {
        unfinished = 'true';
      }
    }
    if (unfinished == 'true') {
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Before the exit blocker is activated (via submit button):

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Edit product" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" data-disable-with="Edit product">
```

After the exit blocker is activated (via submit button):

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Edit product" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" data-disable-with="Edit product" disabled="">
```

As you can see, it's adding `disabled=""` when it's on my website for some reason.

A form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @pack, url: pack_path(@pack), method: :patch do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.input :title, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :pack_type, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :category_id, prompt: "Select Category", collection: [ "sample-pack", "vocal-pack", "preset-pack", "track-pixel", "track-indie", "track-orchestral"], input_html: { class: "form-control center" } %>
  <%= f.input :price, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :audio_embed, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :video_embed, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :art_link, prompt: "ENTER N/A IF STRACK", class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.input :download_url, class: "form-control center" %>
  <%= f.submit "Edit product", class: "btn btn-warning btn-block" %>
<% end %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", packs_path, class: "btn btn-danger top-drop" %>
```

Comment: Try adding an `onsubmit` to the form that sets `window.onbeforeunload` to `null`. Edit: wait, does the script set `unfinished` to `true` even if the form is valid? If so, just fix that (for instance by assigning a value to your `type="submit"` input).

Comment: Either do what @ChrisG suggested or check a flag (boolean) variable in `onbeforeunload` and set that in your `onsubmit` function. Oh and return true from your `onsubmit` function or it wont actually submit.

Comment: Please add your HTML and thus create a [mcve] so we can reproduce / fix this.

Comment: Looking at this again, shouldn't it be `if (inputs[i].value == '')`? An empty input should set the form to unfinished I guess, not a non-empty one? Edit: where's the code that disables the button?

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't block the form submission if both fields are filled: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xu687Lfk/ I have no idea how the button gets disabled, you need to find out which code does that. Nothing in the code you posted does it.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry, I made some changes to the question to hopefully better explain my problem. It seems to be a problem with either Rails, Simple_form, or Bootstrap it seems.

Comment: @AdamH I made some changes to the question to hopefully better explain my problem. It seems to be a problem with either Rails, Simple_form, or Bootstrap it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I took a bit of time and built an example of how I would approach this type of problem. A couple of things to not are;

- I created a global variable `formSubmitting` that is being used to see if the form is being submitted and in the `onsubmit` event of the form I set that to true
- I replaced the for loop that was running over all the elements to use a combination of [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) If you need to support IE 11 then you will need to replace the call to filter with a for loop doing the same test
- The process for warning the user is as follows:

  - If the form isn't being submitted
  - If the form doesn't have the `disabled` attribute
  - If the form has any text boxes that *are not* empty

    - warn the user about leaving the page

```js
// Global variable used to determin if the form is being submitted
// This is used to determine if the user is navigating away from the page
// or trying to submit the form
var formSubmitting = false;

function findNonEmptyInputsInForm(formName) {
  // the css selector we are using here breaks down like this
  // -  form[id="' + formName + '"]
  //    Find the specific formwe want to check the textboxes in
  // -  > fieldset 
  //    We are only interested in the fieldsets in that form
  // -  > input[type="text"]
  //    we only want the inputs in that fieldset that are textboxes

  var cssSelector = 'form[id="' + formName + '"] > fieldset > input[type="text"]';

  // Call filter on the Array to only find elements that
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector), (e) => e.value != '')
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  // check if the form is being submitted
  // we don't want to block the user from 
  // submittng the form
  if (!formSubmitting) {
    // reset the formSubmitting flag
    formSubmitting = false;
    // pull the disabled attribute from the form
    var formDisabled = document.forms["test"].getAttribute('disabled') === "";

    // check if the disabled attribute has been added
    // to the form, we don't want to prevent navigation
    // if the disabled attribute is on the form
    if (!formDisabled) {
      // find all the textboxes that have a value
      var noneEmptyElements = findNonEmptyInputsInForm('test');
      // check if the user has entered any values in the textbox
      // we don't want to prevent navigation if the user 
      // hasn't modified the form
      if (noneEmptyElements.length > 0) {
        // display the confirmation
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
      }
    }
  }

  // reset the formSubmitting flag
  formSubmitting = false;
}
```

```html
<form id="test" name="test" action="/" onsubmit="formSubmitting = true;">
  <fieldset form="test">
    <label for="test_input">Test Element 1</label>
    <input id="test_input" type="text" /><br/>


    <label for="test_input2">Test Element 2</label>
    <input id="test_input2" type="text" /><br/>


    <label for="test_input3">Test Element 3</label>
    <input id="test_input3" type="text" /><br/><br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is a link to a fiddle that you can play around with and add/remove the `disabled` attribute. [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/p6umw3t4/)